# Swift Version conflict after adding TRON library with version 4.1.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swifty-json, tron

I am getting the below version conflict after adding the below line to the Pod file

```
pod 'TRON', '~> 4.1.0'
```

**Error:**

```
   SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'SwiftyJSON')
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest TRON released version is 5.0.0-beta.1, which has Swift 5 support. Earlier releases does not have swift 5 support. You seems to be using TRON 4.1.2 version which has only Swift 4.0 support and not even 4.1 or 4.2 support. So think twice before using older version in newer Swift.

**Other Observations:**

It looks like "SwiftyJSON" is supported for Swift 5 only in 4.3 version. I just tried installing TRON in Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2 and it was installed without any issues. But it downloaded only SwiftyJSON 4.2 version which does not have Swift 5 support. Please find the details below.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestProject' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestProject

pod 'TRON', '~> 4.1.0'
end
```

Installation logs:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (4.7.3)
Installing SwiftyJSON (4.2.0)
Installing TRON (4.1.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 3 total pods installed.
```

Alamofire and SwiftyJSOn get automatically downloaded.So try adding SwiftyJSON 4.3  before TRON in your pod file.

Comment: @kartheek, Was this helpful? is your problem resolved?